# jquery validation not working in partialview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. but jquery validation is not working in partialview.

let me explain what I did

I am loading parial view from parent (**It is not ajax load**)

Parent

```
 <div id="EmailInformationBlock" class="profileSection">
    <div class="sectionTitle">
        <span>Email</span>
    </div>
    <div id="DivEmailContainer" style="display:block">
        @Html.Partial("_DisplayEmail", Model)
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "frmEmail", id = "frmEmail" }))
{

    <td>@Html.Label("Email Location", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>                  
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CommunicationLocation,
                        Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"Select                 ",
                                   new { @class = "input-validation-error form-control",
                                   @name="CommunicationLocationEmail" }
                        )

                }
          </td>
    }

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("selectNone",
            function (value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || element.selectedIndex != 0;
            },
           "Please select an option."
        );
    $("#frmEmail").validate({
        rules: {
            CommunicationLocation: {
                selectNone: true
            }

        },
        messages: {
            CommunicationLocation: {
                selectNone: "This field is required"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            ('#frmEmail').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'customer/PostEditEmail',
                    type: 'Post',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        // $('#DivEmailContainer').html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });


        $.ajax({
            url: "customer/GetCommunicationLocationList",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(d) {
                // states is your JSON array
                var data = d.Data;
                // alert(JSON.stringify(d.Data));
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                    if (data[i].Description != "Bulk Dues"){
                        var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                            data[i].Code + '">' + data[i].Description + '</option>';
                        $("#CommunicationLocation").append(optionhtml);
                    }

                });
            },
            error: function (xhr) { alert("Something seems Wrong"); }
        });
    });


</script>
```

After I submit form is redirecting to new url. It shouldn't go to any url.

[image]

what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Refer to documentation:   http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler

Answer (score 0):

You effectively have `ajax` within a `submit` within a `submit`...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    ('#frmEmail').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
                ....
        });
    });
}
```

You forgot the `$` in front of the `('#frmEmail')` selector, which breaks everything inside the `submitHandler`, but that's not really the core issue here.

> After I submit form is redirecting to new url.

You do not need to put `.ajax()` within a `.submit()` handler when you're already inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` function.  That's the whole point of [the `submitHandler` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler)... to replace the default `submit` handler of the form.

This is all you'd need....

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'customer/PostEditEmail',
        type: 'Post',
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            // $('#DivEmailContainer').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Also note that `$(this).serialize` is replaced with `$(form).serialize()` since `this` is meaningless inside the context of the `submitHandler`.  The `form` argument is already passed into this function by the developer to represent the `form` object.

---

If you're using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin, then you cannot call `.validate()` yourself since `unobtrusive` already handles it for you.  In other words, the jQuery Validate plugin only pays attention to *first* time the `.validate()` method is called, so if your instance is subsequent, then it's ignored along with your options.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it looks like jquery is not aware that the partial view has any validation because it is loaded from a parent view.
Try reparsing the DOM by adding the following to your partial view

```
$(function(){
   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#frmEmail");
});
```

and this to you parent view

```
$(function(){
   $("#submitButtonId").click(function(){
   if (!$("#frmEmail").valid()){
      return false;
   }
});
});
```